# How to block transaction in one of android kiosk, if another kiosk is using same

Tags: android

I have 3 android kiosk in same network, I am performing an action on one kiosk, that includes scanning the bar code and making a lock open on next screen and then one api call to give success.

I want to restrict another kiosks scanning same barcode until above action that i performed on kiosk one completes.

How do I need to handle, either on backend or locally on android side?

Answer (score 0):

The backend needs to know when a client started the transaction (posted the value of the barcode) and tell the other clients, that a transaction is in progress. The same goes for having completed the transaction. I'd just use a navigation graph for said "transaction", where the first screen would permit scanning - then one can permit or deny the navigation, depending if someone else may scan. However, from a business perspective, this seems to be a huge waste of time ...when the backend cannot handle N transactions - which are meant to perform isolated anyway.